# Psalm 110. God's Right-Hand-Man. David or Messiah? Potential blasphemy

Tags: tehilim-psalms, heresy

Ok whoever this passage is about is shown sitting at the right hand of God in [verse 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.110.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Being someone's right hand man means one's primary or most trusted assistant. Unless this meant something different in the ancient Hebrew (which I doubt), my question is that if this passage is about David, and that makes David, God's most trusted or primary assistant, then what does that mean to the Messiah? Will the Messiah be the second most trusted assistant?

My second question is, that in [verse 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.110.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), we see God at the right hand of this person. Now that seems like a blasphemy to me because it's like saying a King is your right hand man as opposed to you being the King's right hand man. How do you guys resolve this to not become a blasphemy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Psalm 110 in Jewish Tradition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95810/psalm-110-in-jewish-tradition)

Comment: @magicker72 Nope unfortunately it doesn't even touch on the blasphemy issue. Neither does it answer the first question.

Comment: I don't understand teh second question. David goes in to battle but, though he leads his troops, he has God's assistance so metaphorically, God is "on his side". As per Malbim, "וה' על ימינך לעזרך במלחמה, עתה ה' על ימינך, ה' אשר מחץ ביום אפו מלכים שכבר כבש לפניך את עיר המלוכה ומחץ את המלכים שבה" How is it blasphemy to say that David had God's help and didn't conquer based solely on his own might?

Answer (score 2):

As far as your first question it is worth noting the [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.110.1?lang=bi&p2=Malbim_on_Psalms.110.1.1&lang2=bi) who writes that this terminology of Dovid sitting on His right is not a reference to him being Hashem's second in command but rather it is Hashem attesting to the fact that it is only really G-d who sits on the throne of Israel and controls the Jewish peoples' destiny. He therefore asks Dovid to sit on His right so that he can truly recognise that Dovid is a mere mortal king and only serves as Hashem's assistant.

> שב לימיני, יצייר שכסא דוד הוא כסא ה' כמ"ש וישב שלמה על כסא ה' למלך, כאלו ה' יושב על כסא ההנהגה להנהיג את ישראל בהשגחה מיוחדת, כמלך המנהיג את עמו, ודוד יושב על כסא המלוכה לימינו, ובאשר היושב על הכסא צריך הדום לרגליו
>
> Sit at my right: Hashem is delineating that the throne of Dovid is really the throne of Hashem. Like it writes "And Shlomo sat on the throne of G-d as king" ([Divrei HaYamim I 29:23](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.29.23?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)). It is as if Hashem sits on the throne of leadership to lead Israel under its special supervision like a king who leads his people. And Dovid is sitting on the throne to the right, and as for him who sits on the throne he needs the footstool at his feet.

Answer (score 1):

The verse is not saying that G-d is his "right-hand man", which is not an expression found in Biblical Hebrew. The verse is saying G-d is assisting him in his endeavors, carried out through his right hand.

In Jewish thought, no one can accomplish anything without G-d's help. If someone merits that G-d helps them regularly, we say G-d's presence is "with" them, metaphorically speaking. So G-d's presence is at David's right hand, assisting him. But the way you merit G-d's assistance is trying to fulfill his will.

Comment: It doesn't have to say "right hand man". The picture of having someone on your right hand is understood as such, based on my understanding at least. Is there any other scripture in the Tanakh that shows mere mortals either being at God's right hand or having God at their right hand or both such as this example? I've been looking and haven't been able to find any.

Comment: You write: "based on my understanding at least". In my experience, if my understanding makes something not make sense to me, my understanding is wrong. The concept of a right hand man did not exist back then, whatever you want to call it.

Comment: Can you give an example in the Tanakh of where someone known, a mere mortal, not up to interpretation such as this text, is shown at God's right hand and God is also shown at his right hand?

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: @N.T. Did "right hand man" really not exist? What of https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.2.19

Comment: @DoubleAA That is just a place of honor. What does that have to do with "right hand man"?

Comment: @Mordecai G-d is described in other places as supporting or protecting a mortal's "right hand." For example in Psalm 16:8 ("שִׁוִּ֬יתִי יְ-ה לְנֶגְדִּ֣י תָמִ֑יד כִּ֥י מִֽ֝ימִינִ֗י בַּל־אֶמּֽוֹט"); Psalm 121:5 ("יְ-ה שֹׁמְרֶ֑ךָ יְ-ה צִ֝לְּךָ֗ עַל־יַ֥ד יְמִינֶֽךָ"); Isaiah 41:3 ("מַחֲזִ֣יק יְמִינֶ֑ךָ הָאֹמֵ֥ר לְךָ֛ אַל־תִּירָ֖א אֲנִ֥י עֲזַרְתִּֽיךָ"). .
And the people of Israel--who are mortal--are described as being G-d's right hand man in Psalm 80:18 "תְּֽהִי־יָ֭דְךָ עַל־אִ֣ישׁ יְמִינֶ֑ךָ עַל־בֶּן־אָ֝דָ֗ם אִמַּ֥צְתָּ לָּֽךְ"
There are probably more if you take the time to look.

Comment: @conceptualinertia Thanks for those references. My thoughts on them: Psalm 16:8 is Messianic in my view and verse 10 talks about an immediate resurrection referring to the body of the Holy One not seeing decay. In Psalm 121:5, what is at your right hand is your shade. I know it says the LORD is that shade but it's not exactly the same kind of picture we get in Psalm 16:8 or Psalm 110. Now Isaiah 41:13 talks about God taking hold of your right hand. That means you must be at God's left hand? Not really the same thing. And Psalm 80:18 is referring to one person again, singular, the Messiah.

Comment: @Mordecai You asked for other places where G-d is described as helping man's right hand or a man is described at being at G-d's right hand. I provided these. A Christian might read all of these as referring to Jesus but that is not their simple meaning. For example, Psalm 80:18 specifically refers to G-d's right hand man as being a mere mortal "son of Man." Similarly Psalm 16:8 in context isn't remotely messianic. The Psalm is a prayer of David, a mortal, praising G-d, expressing his loyalty to G-d, and thanking Him for His bounty.  (I don't understand your response to Isaiah 41:3).

Comment: Saying "the body of the Holy One" is outright blasphemy in Judaism. I think you would be better off on a different SE network, where people with no understanding of Biblical Hebrew decide what they would like the Bible to say.